# hi when i want add package to project recived to error down

Tags: flutter, package

===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 431:12     Entrypoint._get

===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 265:7      Entrypoint.acquireDependencies

This is an unexpected error. Please run

```
dart pub --trace get --no-precompile
```

and include the logs in an issue on https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/new

pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...

HTTP error 403: Forbidden

package:pub/src/http.dart 229:5            _ThrowingClient.send

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: i use vscode IDE

Answer (score 0):

its happening because your network connection is not proper or the server is not allowed to your country, or something wrong with your flutter

here is some ways to fix that problem i know

1-
use a vpn or proxy (its showing cant connect to the server so try to change the IP)

2-
check this link if vpn method is not working - https://dart.dev/tools/pub/troubleshoot#pub-get-fails-from-behind-a-corporate-firewall

3 -
try to upgrade your flutter just by one command

```
flutter upgrade
```

4 -
if its not working try to clean by this command

```
flutter clean
```

5 -
if anything wont working try to reinstall flutter (not recommended )